# Read all of the terminal command history in OS X

Tags: macos, terminal

It would be great to access all my commands run in terminal on OS X so I can review and use as a running reminder sheet.

I'm using Reverse-I-Search prompt, and have updated my .bash_profile to store all of my history as mentioned here on [Mactoids: How to search Terminal command history](http://web.archive.org/web/20150102042708/http://mactoids.com/how-to-search-terminal-command-history/).

1. Start Terminal.
2. Navigate to the Home folder by entering:

   ```
   cd ~/
   ```
3. Create .bash_profile by entering:

   ```
   touch .bash_profile
   ```
4. Now, either edit .bash_profile in your favorite text editor or type this in the Terminal window to automatically open the file in the default TextEdit:

   ```
   open -e .bash_profile
   ```
5. Lastly, add this to the .bash_profile file:

   ```
   HISTFILESIZE=1000000000 HISTSIZE=1000000
   ```
6. Save and exit.

Do you have any ideas how I could access in order to output the terminal command history in OS X?

Comment: I presume you've read `man bash`, so you should know that the history is stored in the file `~/.bash_history`.  What else do you need to know, can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, because I new the 'man' command existed then read the manual found the answer and decided to ask the question above just for the fun of it. Thanks fideli for quick, clear and unpretentious answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All of your history is stored in `~/.bash_history`, where both `reverse-i-search` and the up/down keys use. That file is regularly pruned, but if you followed the guide in your link, the `.bash_history` file will practically never be pruned.

Comment: FIFO or LIFO pruning?

Comment: @Pacerier, I can't be completely sure as I no longer use macOS but if I had to guess, FIFO pruning.

Comment: sometimes not `~/.bash_history` but `~/.zsh_history`

Answer (score 31):

In modern versions of MacOS (Catalina and up) you'll find your bash history in `~/.zsh_history` by default:

```
cat ~/.zsh_history
```

Comment: This is the one. This returns the complete history, where as "history" only returns the current session history.  M1 Mac.

Comment: Well, you'll find your `zsh` history in `~/.zsh-history`, and that will probably be what you want. You probably won't find your `bash` history in `~/.zsh-history` unless you've done some very odd things with your configuration. (`bash` and `zsh` are both shell programs. `bash` used to be the default, but Apple switched to `zsh` being the default. `bash` is still installed and, if you use it, its history will still be in `~/.bash_history`)

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would prefer to do it in a simpler way and **print everything**, instead of checking the latest session which doesn't cover all Terminal windows and all commands.

**Get a full history**

```
cd ~/.bash_sessions
cat *.historynew *.history
```

**If you want to sort by session date**

```
cd ~/.bash_sessions
cat `ls -tr *.historynew *.history`
```

Answer (score 5):

per https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/423463/how-to-display-the-full-command-history-in-terminal -

```
history 0
```

Will output the full history

Answer (score 2):

In case you still need a fix for this, here's how I did mine. With this, I can SAVE AND ACCESS history across all tabs (i.e. if you enter a command on one tab, then open a new tab and press up, it will suggest the command you just entered in the previous tab)

### You'll need 2 things: 1. Enter this command in your terminal to make sure histappend is turned on:

```
shopt -s histappend && shopt histappend
```

### 2. You'll also need to know where your history commands are being stored.

My history files are stored in ~/.bash_sessions so that's what my code will reflect. If yours are stored in ~/.bash_history, or another directory, just swap that for ~/.bash_sessions when we source it into our bash_profile.

Once you've figured that out, open your bash_profile and add the following code:

```
source ~/.bash_sessions/*.history        #<--sources prev sessions through your bash_profile. If you don't use ~/.bash_sessions to store your history, replace it with whatever you use (i.e. source ~/.bash_history/*.history

export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups #<-- auto-erases duplicates in your history
export HISTSIZE=1000                    #<-- assigns # of results to return
export HISTFILESIZE=100000              #<-- assigns # of results to store in your .bash_history
shopt -s histappend                     #<-- appends & saves history throughout all tabs

export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"  <--appends history from all tabs, clears & uses appended history file as current
```

Comment: be aware that running `source ~/.bash_sessions/*.history` executes all the commands

Answer (score 0):

`history ~` works for me on Ventura 13.4.1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).