# Terminal is showing computer name as a weird number?

Tags: macos, terminal, terminal.app

I have a Macbook Pro and I use the terminal quite often. So as usual, I launched terminal today and I saw:

```
Last login: Sun May  8 13:20:40 on ttys000
172-15-43-17:~ koraytugay$
```

Until today, I am very sure that instead of **172-15-43-17** I used to see **Koray 's Macbook** because that was the name of my computer.

Why might this be?

Comment: It looks suspiciously like an IP address. Are remotely accessing a server in the US?

Comment: This answer may help diagnose the commands that have been run in the terminal. http://superuser.com/questions/308919/read-all-of-the-terminal-command-history-in-os-x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason (that I've been too lazy to research...) OS X has 3 distinct names for the host computer: ComputerName, HostName and LocalHostName. You can view each of them with a simple loop

```
$  for name in ComputerName HostName LocalHostName; do scutil --get $name; done
MY_MAC
My_MAC
SaxDaddy-MAC
```

As you can see, they can be different. You can use the `--set` option to change them

```
sudo scutil --set HostName
```

One of these is off, probably your HostName. GL